# Calculating the acreage of a created polygon in ArcGIS Collector

Tags: area, polygon-creation, arcgis-collector

I recently set up an app using ArcGIS Collector. I have a editable polygon shapefile that has an acreage field. It allows me to create a new polygon, but requires that I enter in the acreage field value manually. Of course I don't know what the actual acreage. Is there a way to automatically calculate that field when it is created in Collector or do I need to wait and calculate it after I sync back to ArcMap?

Comment: You need to do this either manually when you access the feature after the sync back to the server. Or you can set up a script to calculate and update the feature.

Comment: Any suggestions on where to inject a script? Any resources/documentation on how to do that? I am not seeing anything obvious.

Comment: Are you running off of Portal or ArcGIS Online?

Comment: Data was created in ArcMap--> opened into ArcGIS Online --> and then wired to my Collector app using my ArcGIS Online account.

Comment: Ok I am not familiar with that workflow. I will try and play around with my accounts today and let you know what I can see. But for me, I serve my data from a server to my Portal Account, I can then set up scripts to run and push new updates to my Portal and subsequently my Collector. Depending on your needs for Collector, Survey123 might provide you with an alternative.